# Проверка добавленных символов в textarea во время печати

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется заранее заданный список слов. Пользователь начинает печатать. Как только программа находит совпадение с `{b` или `;b` или   `b` - всплывает окно, со списком всех заданных слов на букву **b**

Идея взята отсюда - https://liveweave.com/ (напечатайте <a, например)

Может есть какая-то хитрая функция, которую нужно просто знать? По сути, ключевой вопрос в том, чтобы получить значение двух последних напечатанных символов (которые могут оказаться и посреди текста). Остальное уже детали.

Comment: Слушайте событие `onkeyup`, пишите логику по сохранению нажатых символов.

Comment: Я что-то такое уже отвечал про автодополнение после символа `@`, но не получается найти: https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/edit/995087.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вариант, перехватываем нажатие кнопки и записываем в переменную, которую и отслеживаем. Если переменная более двух символов, то обрезаем первый и добавляем второй.

```js
var data = '';
$('#target').keyup(function(e) {
  if (data.length > 1) data = data.slice(1, 2);
  data = data + e.key;
  $("#result").html('Result: ' + data);
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

textarea {
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  min-height: 30vh
}

#result {
  padding: 1rem
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="target">Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут, рыбные тексты. Мир все семь повстречался вопрос языкового если агентство но, великий рыбными себя, оксмокс маленький, за речью ручеек обеспечивает строчка большой всеми они живет! запятых страну даль решила океана до всеми они ее толку раз.</textarea>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо)) Надо было знать про .key

Comment: Да иногда не хватает малого, вот тут хороший пример там много данных в event https://api.jquery.com/keyup/